# Ajax call to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery, combobox

I already have a function where I am getting data from database and fill it in HTML table on combo-box change event basically I am doing this using ajax.

But every time I am calling the database on combo-box change which is not efficient. So, now I decided I fill the data in the html table initially on page load and then filter out from the HTML table instead of every time going to the database and filter it.

So is there any way of filter out data from the html table on combo box change event? or it is possible to call ajax on html table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put classes on each `<tr>` which match values on the combo-box items. When an option is selected, show any rows that have a class that matches a value of the selected options.

```
<select id="options" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>

<table>
    <tr class="red green">
        <td>red or green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="blue">
        <td>blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="yellow black">
        <td>yellow or black</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="blue yellow">
        <td>blue or yellow</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select#options").change(function () {
        var selections = [];

        $(this).children(':selected').each(function (index, option) {
            selections.push(option.value);
        });

        console.log(selections);
        $("table tr").each(function (index, row) {
            $(row).hide();
            for(var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
                if($(row).hasClass(selections[i])) {
                    $(row).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

That was fun. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MbzyV/)

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate solution depends on how much data there is and whether different table joins are required.

You could store the data in a JavaScript array, then retrieve the data you need from that array and build your HTML table.

You could use a library to facilitate SQL like queries on the data. Have a look at [jslinq](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/). Example:

```
var myList = [
        {FirstName:"Chris",LastName:"Pearson"},
        {FirstName:"Kate",LastName:"Johnson"},
        {FirstName:"Josh",LastName:"Sutherland"},
        {FirstName:"John",LastName:"Ronald"},
        {FirstName:"Steve",LastName:"Pinkerton"}
        ];

var exampleArray = JSLINQ(myList)
        .Where(function(item){ return item.FirstName == "Chris"; })
        .OrderBy(function(item) { return item.FirstName; })
        .Select(function(item){ return item.FirstName; });
```

If you don't want to just serve all the data with the page (ie. there's a lot of data) then you could use AJAX to retrieve data as it's needed and store it so that if it is needed again, you've already got it in the browser. In other words, each time you get new data from the actual database, you add that data to whatever is currently stored until eventually you might have a complete copy of the DB in the browser.

Depending on the complexity of your data, you will need to come up with a method of knowing whether you've already got the required data in-browser, or if a new AJAX request is required.

If you want a more tailored answer, perhaps edit the question to include details of the database schema and an example query.